# Why is the CSS Transition on background-size not working?

Tags: css, transition, background-size

**Demo:** [http://everythinghomegrown.com/] (look at the *Customize Your Own* section with the four batman images)

For some reason, the background-size is not transitioning. Instead it jumps from one size to the other without a smooth transition.

---

```
div {
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

div:hover, div:focus {
  background-size: 115% 115%;
}
```

Why is the transition not working? I’m experiencing this in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: Please include the minimal amount of code in your question so we can reproduce the problem. Not just a link to your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Originally I had this:

```
div {
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

div:hover, div:focus {
  background-size: 115% 115%;
}
```

I fixed the problem by adding a second value to the background-size property.

```
div {
  background-size: 100% 100%; /* added second 100% to fix the problem */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

div:hover, div:focus {
  background-size: 115% 115%;
}
```